# How to use multiple versions of GCC

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

We have a new application that requires glibc 2.4 (from gcc 4.1). The machine we have runs on has gcc 3.4.6.   We can not upgrade, and the application must be run on this machine.

We installed gcc 4.1, however, when it comes to compile time it is using all the includes, etc, from 3.4.6.

How do we get around this?

Any suggestions on using 4.1 for just this application?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Refer "How to install multiple versions of GCC" [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple) in the GNU GCC FAQ.

There's also a white paper [here](http://www.tellurian.com.au/whitepapers/multiplegcc.php).

Answer (score 4):

for Ubuntu it's pretty easy

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test`

`sudo apt-get update`

and then install for example gcc version 6

`sudo apt-get install gcc-6`

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `gcc-select`? Otherwise, try setting the `INCLUDE_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` in your shell.

Comment: can't find it anymore, any idea if this package still exist or has changed name?

Comment: That sounds like something distribution specific. Reminds me of Gentoo or Debian but I am not sure.

Comment: @dave I've never used Gentoo, this definitely exists on other systems as well. Might have been Debian, I can't remember.

Answer (score 3):

update-alternatives is a very good way to have multiple gcc versions:

http://ubuntuguide.net/how-to-install-and-setup-gcc-4-1g4-1-in-ubuntu-10-0410-10

Answer (score 2):

You possibly still execute the old gcc. Try making a symlink from `gcc` to your version of it, like

```
ln -s gcc-4.1 gcc
```

Beware of not removing an old "gcc" binary placed there, in case they placed not just a symlink. If you can recompile your own gcc version, the safest is just use another prefix at configure time of gcc, something like `--prefix=/home/jojo/usr/gcc` (i did it that way with gcc-4.4 from svn-trunk, and it worked great).

Note that that just runs the right gcc version. If you update your gcc, your glibc won't be updated automatically too. It's a separate package which is deeply coupled with the rest of the system. Be careful when installing another glibc version.

Comment: You can view the output of ls -l to see if the gcc in a directory is a file or a symlink.