# Implenting wireless sensor routing protocol in NS2

Tags: ns2

I am trying to implement a routing protocol in NS2.

I tried ns2 2.29 + mannasim but my Linux is having a different gcc than gcc4.3 . So I could not patch the ns2 all in one code with mannasim.  mannasim for ns2 2.35 is not available, and when it is available, I'm not sure it will run with this version of gcc.

Has anyone tried successfully running ns2+mannasim with gcc 4.7?

If there is any other alternative to mannasim also it enough for me to simulate a WSN?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate protocol for sensor network then used Mannasim patch otherwise no need to use this patch for ad-hoc network.

Now for ns-allinone-2.35 Mannasim patch is available. Enjoy...!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you need nanasim for you simulation or could you achieve the same effect with ad-hoc?
2. If not, probably the easiest way to go would be to install the desired version of gcc in adition to the one you have [How to use multiple versions of GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448457/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-gcc)
3. Otherwise you could try to port the namasim code to the latest ns2 version yourself. If you are somewhat familiar with tcl and c++, this could not be as hard as it sounds. Usually the ns2 patches fail due to changed line numbers, and the changes can be applied manually by examining the patch file. [Note that this could fail if you are unlucky and there are significant differences in the ns2 source files, but this is usually not the case. - Backup everything just in case though]

Answer (score 0):

Mannasim can also be used in ns2.34. Here is the link to patch Mannasim to NS2.34.

The link also provides all the steps to deal with the errors during the installation.

However, there is a typo in #include . It should be #include  .

Everything else works excellently.

http://old.nabble.com/Re%3A-Installing-MANNASIM-patch-in-NS-2.34-p34588016.html

Good Luck! :)