# Update gcc just for current user

Tags: linux, gcc

Can I update Gcc just for the current user not change the whole Linux system? I am using it on a shared computer, I have no sufficient level of authority。 thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, but in a nutshell : build yourselves from sources.

You can you use Gentoo Prefix (if it's still alive), Nix package manager, etc. to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

You should not update for selected user, but install multiple versions in parallel. So every user is able to use any compiler which is needed. But this has also some drawbacks! And getting all the shared library stuff managed can be also a task which is not always easy to solve.

Take a first look at:
https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple

Maybe this questions helps a bit:
[How to use multiple versions of GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448457/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-gcc)

Answer (score 0):

Acknowledging it's no small learning curve, Gentoo Linux is very good about making multiple versions of gcc available at once. What I'm not so sure about is how to go about institutionalizing things so that a given user's invocation of simply "gcc" will call a specific version controlled by that user.