# how to setup a cross-compiler on linux?

Tags: linux

my machine already have cross compiler toolchain in a folder.
how do I tell machine to compile using this cross compiler rather than the native compiler?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use multiple versions of GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448457/608639)

Comment: Run the cross-compiler rather instead of the native compiler, that's enough.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk 
thanks. I was thinking I need set up environment. to my surprise. gcc compiler knows where to find header folder, lib folder and the link command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no need to setup anything. just run the compiler. compiler have internal setup, knows where to find relevant files for build.